# location.hostname of some web pages is not accurate

Tags: javascript, browser, adsense, google-ads-api, hostname

I'm writing a bookmarklet that reads `location.hostname` of the current page.

On most sites this works fine, i.e. for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask it returns `http://stackoverflow.com`.

But on some sites it does not work. For example, on http://techslides.com/over-2000-d3-js-examples-and-demos it returns `googleads.g.doubleclick.net`.

I've figured out that I can get the 'original' hostname `http://techslides.com` using `location.ancestorOrigins[0]`

Using this, I've written the following attempt to get an accurate hostname on any site:

```
function getHostname() {
  var previous_hostnames = window.ancestorOrigins;
  if (previous_hostnames) {
    return previous_hostnames[0];
  } else {
    return window.hostname;
  }
}
```

I'm wondering:

1. Why is this happening?
2. Is my approach adequate?

Can assume I'm just running on Chrome, if it makes things easier.

Chrome build:

```
Version 52.0.2743.116 (64-bit)
Platform 8350.68.0 (Official Build) stable-channel orco
Firmware Google_Orco.5216.362.7
```

---

*in response to comments*

neither `location.host` or `location.origin` work

```
location.host
"googleads.g.doubleclick.net"
location.origin
"https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net"
```

Comment: What about `location.host` or `location.origin`?

Comment: @Scott doesn't work, see updated question with proof

Comment: Hmm, I tried both on that 2000 D3 examples site, and they both return the correct result.  Even `.hostname` works for me though.  Not running Adblock or anything like that.  Hopefully somebody else can weigh in on this, sorry!

Comment: thanks @Scott for trying it on your computer. The fact that it worked made me think it was one of my chrome extensions causing the error - disabling them all proved this correct.

Comment: It _doesn't_ return that. Tried Firefox and Chrome. Question 1: are you trying this in Chrome dev tools? If so, Question 2: are you being bitten by [this bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=637618&q=frame%20dev%20tools&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified)

Comment: @Vid see my posted answer

Comment: @maxpleaner was the frame selected correct, though? It might be nothing to do with extensions. When Chrome opens a random one, it would, pretty much by definition, give you a random value for `location`. This bug is _still_ happening at least as far as version `52.0.2743.116` which is what I have installed now in Windows and it's up to date - I still get a random frame selected when I open the dev tools. If I don't change to `top` I get random values for `location`. So clarifying if it's the aforementioned bug or not is the difference between `location` actually being hijacked or not.

Comment: @Vld not sure how to reproduce it actually. Re-enabling my extensions didn't produce the same error

Comment: @maxpleaner than that suggests it's the Chrome bug. If you open the dev tools, go to the console look at the top of the window - just below the tabs and to the left of the checkbox called `Preserve log`. That is the currently selected frame for the console context. Choose `top` from the dropdown and that will be the correct one that is _supposed_ to be the default. If you switch to a different context (iframes, extensions) the `window` object (as well as `location`) is going to be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the error was caused by one of my Chrome Extensions (not sure which, will try and determine later).

Disabling all the extensions brought back the correct `location.hostname`